# Elasticsearch document structure for performance optimization

Tags: multithreading, elasticsearch, optimization, querydsl

In Elasticsearch is it better to query on 50 fields in 1,000,000 documents or 1 field in 50,000,000 documents. I'll explain my problem with an example:

For case 1, our doc looks like:

```
doc1: {
    "f1": "abc",
    "f2": "pqr",
    "f3": "lmn",
    ...
    "f50": "xyz"
}
```

Here a should query will be performed from "f1" to "f50".

For case 2, our doc will look like:

```
doc1.1: {
    "f": "abc"
}

doc1.2: {
    "f": "pqr"
}    

doc1.3: {
    "f": "lmn"
}
...
...
doc1.50: {
    "f": "xyz"
}
```

Let's just say I am concerned about the docs containing the queried value irrespective of the field.

Comment: There are so many unknowns (number of shards, number of nodes, is it a cacheable filter,...) that I don't think you can get an authoritative answer. IMO this should be small enough that it doesn't make much difference and you're overthinking it. Just build it and if it blows up / gets slow, think about refactoring. If you just have a few GB of data and use regular queries, it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the 50 million documents approach. ElasticSearch can handle that size easily with proper hardware (self experience), and it will be much easier for querying and data manipulation.

Comment: Can you please explain why it will be easier for querying ?

Comment: I think by easy he means we will have to write a query/mapping for one field only rather than 50 fields.

Comment: @demas yes. It is easier for the developer to query/map only 1 field. Also, if you are using query, instead of search, I recommend to you to use MongoDB. Read https://everypageispageone.com/2011/07/13/search-vs-query/ for more information.